# Flutter String variable cant be assigned

Tags: flutter, dart

I do not understand what is wrong here as I have copied and pasted code from a youtube video. The reason why I have put var in front of accepting user input is because if I put String as the guy in the video did it just wont work for me, but for him it works, the video is 8 months old, has something changed with Flutter, am I missing something or am I just plain dumb...?

```
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  print("Enter first number: ");
  var num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Enter second number: ");
  var num2 = stdin.readLineSync();
  print(
  int.parse(num1) + int.parse(num2)
 );

}
```

Comment: What error is coming while puting String instead of var?

Comment: Dart 2.12 with null-safety was released near the beginning of this year.  The video you watched likely was written for Dart 2.10 or earlier.

Comment: @jamesdlin okay but how do I then convert user string input to integer, i have tried int.parse method and it doesnt work... :(

Comment: @AnasNadeem error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: String? num1 = stdin.readLineSync(); try this

Comment: @coding4life See the answers at the linked question.